# Compare 2 Guids in a conditional Split in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am  building a conditional split in SSIS to figure out if a row is new or updated. One of the columns I want to compare is a guid and it allows null.

I tried to compare the column like COLUMN != Destination_COLUMN. However I am not allowed to compare guids. Thoughts on workarounds as i have a lot of guids in the DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the derived column transformation to create string versions of your GUIDs, and compare the string columns instead of the GUID columns.